# java: Dynamic class loading with an interface to be implemented by the loaded class

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-loading

i am trying to do a dynamic class loading for my uni assignment. Here is the code for an interface and part of the test class.

```
public interface AddressBookDataStore {

    void addPerson(Person p);

    Person[] getPersons(String name);

    void remove(Person p);
    boolean contains(String name);
} 


public class testklasse {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Class clazz =  Class.forName("Addresbook");
        Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

My task is to implement the testclass in such a way that the compiler allows me to load (and not implement!) the methods of Addresbookdatastore which is implemented by the class Addresbook. i honestly don't understand how this is even possible, since we are talking about loading a class that we know nothing about. the method newInstance() is delivering simply nur the object but nothing else.. am i missing something?

thanks!

Mel

Comment: What is `Addressbook`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the assignment. There's no way you can load a class that does not exist. `Addresbook` must be a class that exists and implements `AddressBookDataStore`.

Comment: Can you rephrase the first sentence, "My task is to implement the testclass in ...", after your code? Not sure what you mean exactly by that sentence.

Comment: Addressbook should be a class implementing the methods of the above interface to register or delete names of people on a , well, addresbook.

Comment: well, the assignment is in german, maybe my translation wasn't accurate. my prof.  wants me to create a testclass testing the methods of the above interface using an instance of a class. and we don't have a specific class, it's just a class and i named it addresbook.

Comment: May be the [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class is what you need.

Comment: well it's explicitly mentioned in the assignment not to rely on reflect. just doesn't make sense.. sorry to bother you guys..

Comment: @BheshGurung That seems kind of advanced. OP, maybe you should be creating a class that implements `AddressBookDataStore`?

Comment: no i shouldn't. it is as well explicitly mentioned that the assignment is  about creating a testclass without having a class  that implements AddressBookDataStore

Comment: @melar, that contredicts your question: "the methods of Addresbookdatastore which is implemented by the class Addresbook", if Addressbook implements the interface, you can cast your `object` into that interface and the call the methods

Comment: that is the very reason that i am posting here actually.i'm well aware of it and was trying to make sense of this assignment, sofar with no success..